# How to combine several TS interface files into one index file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, types, rollupjs

I am trying to create a shared types package and want to split up my types based on their domain such as menu or restaurnt etc but then be able to combine them into one file index.d.ts.

The file structure currently looks like this.

```
project
│   index.d.ts
│
└───types
    │   restaurant.d.ts
    │   menus.d.ts
```

My index.d.ts is trying to import the files and then add them to one namespace like so:

```
import Restaurant from './types/restaurant';
import Menus from './types/menus';

export = MyTypes;
export as namespace MyTypes;

declare namespace MyTypes {

  type Restaurant = Restaurant.Restaurant;

  type Menus = Menus.Menus;
}
```

Then my Restaurant namespace looks like this:

```
export = Menus;
export as namespace Menus

declare module Menus {

  export interface Menus {
      id: string;
      name: string;
  }

}
```

However, it does not allow me to export due to the following error:

`'Menus' refers to a UMD global, but the current file is a module. Consider adding an import instead.ts(2686)`

Should I be using `declare module` and the export here?

What is the best way to define my `Menus` type and how should it be imported in the index.d.ts?

Would I be better off using rollup or something?

Comment: You should probably stop using namespaces and `module` here and define your types directly instead of having to mess with imports and exports. It'd be a lot simpler.

Comment: What do you mean defined the types directly? Do you mean all in one file?

Comment: Well, basically, delete your namespaces and leave all your types "naked". You don't need namespaces. You can selectively choose what types you want and don't want to use in a file, so you don't really need a namespace to prevent naming collisions (that's what namespaces are for).

Comment: Does that mean if I remove namespaces then I don't need to bother with `*.d.ts` file naming as it's no longer a declaration file? I would then just need to export these files via the root `index.ts` file?